# How to reset Jasmine Spy object?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocking, jasmine

Not able to find docs for resetting the Jasmine Spy object.
If there is better way of using spy objects, please suggest.

```
// spec.js
import { mockService } from "./mockService"; // mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj(...)

describe('test', () => {
  beforeEach(function () {
    // NOTE: Following don't work

    // mockService.reset();
    // mockService.calls.reset();
    // mockService.method.calls.reset();
  });

  it('a', () => {
    mockService.fn();
    expect(mockService.fn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('b', () => {
    mockService.fn();
    expect(mockService.fn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as expected.

E.g.

```js
const service = {
  fn() {},
};

const mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj(service, 'fn');

describe('test', () => {
  beforeEach(function () {
    mockService.fn.calls.reset();
  });

  it('a', () => {
    mockService.fn();
    expect(mockService.fn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('b', () => {
    mockService.fn();
    expect(mockService.fn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
Randomized with seed 28798
Started
..


2 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0.02 seconds
Randomized with seed 28798 (jasmine --random=true --seed=28798)
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |      80 |     100 |                   
 index.spec.js |     100 |      100 |      80 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I was actually doing `spyObj.calls.reset()` but had to do ``spyObj.spyMethod.calls.reset()``

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect way: `spyObj.calls.reset()`

Correct way: `spyObj.spyMethod.calls.reset()`

**NOTE**: `calls.reset()` is done for spy methods and not for spy object.

[Jasmine reset() docs](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/Spy_calls.html#reset)